# Filter Google Drive API to get Only Google Data studio reports

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, looker-studio

I would like to know if it is possible to filer Google Drive API to get Only Google Data studio Reports.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to resolve it by following

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
   'maxResults': NO_OF_FILES,
   'q': "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-analytics.rap.report'"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent actually tried this recently [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) has several options.

> q  string  A query for filtering the file results. See the "Search for Files and Team Drives" guide for the supported syntax.
>
> spaces string  A comma-separated list of spaces to query within the corpus. Supported values are 'drive', 'appDataFolder' and 'photos'.
>   supportsTeamDrives  boolean Whether the requesting application supports Team Drives. (Default: false)
>
> teamDriveId    string  ID of Team Drive to search.

I beleave that there is another option in spaces that denotes its for team drive.  You could search only those